# Aggregation layer in bidirectional LSTMs

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, tflearn

I am using bidirectional LSTM in the many-to-one setting (sentiment analysis task) with tflearn. I want to understand how does tflearn aggregate representations from the forward and backward LSTM layers before sending it to the softmax layer to get probabilistic output? For instance, in the following diagram, how are concat and aggregate layers usually implemented?

[image]

Is there any documentation available on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using tflearn's [Bidirectional RNN](http://tflearn.org/layers/recurrent/#bidirectional-rnn), the output is concatenated, as you have shown in the above figure. So each of the output will be twice that of the input embedding size. The default setting only returns the last sequence output, so if you want to use the entire sequence, then you need to set `return_seq=True` and then pass the sequence to the aggregration layer like `Merge`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was wondering how come they do not use an aggregation layer in their bidirectional sentiment analysis example shown below.  https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/nlp/bidirectional_lstm.py

Comment: As i said in my answer, the default setting of `bidirectional_rnn` only returns the last sequence output (the output of word3 in your fig). Since this layer depends on the last 2 layers, only this output is good enough for classification. Now the other 2 outputs are ignored, there is no scope for aggregation.